# Symfony 5.2 EntityType value is not Valid with JSON object

Tags: php, symfony

We use Symfony 5.2 as a REST-API for our angular project and can't get Forms to work properly when defining EntityTypes:

We get the following Error when trying to send a JSON object:

```
professionBranch:
ERROR: This value is not valid.
```

Our form:

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('professionBranch', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => ProfessionBranch::class
            ])
        ;
    }
```

Our request Object:

```
{
  "idProfession": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "professionBranch": {
    "idProfessionBranch": 1,
    "name": "Heilmittel"
  }
}
```

When only the id of ProfessionBranch is submitted the form recognizes the Entity and it works. Is there a way to to tell symfony to search for the "idProfessionBranch" key inside the "professionBranch" object as we don't want to change our entire forms on frontend side.

```
  "professionBranch": {
    "idProfessionBranch": 1,
    "name": "Heilmittel"
  }
```

EDIT: Here my attempt of using a datatransformer

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('professionBranch', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => ProfessionBranch::class,
            ]);

        $builder->get('professionBranch')
            ->addModelTransformer($this);

    }

    public function transform($value)
    {
        return $value->getIdProfessionBranch();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
    }
```

The following error message shows when using a datatransformer to return the ID:

```
Argument 1 passed to Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\ChoiceList\\IdReader::getIdValue() must be an object or null, int give
```

Comment: When the data transmitted is not mirroring the Entity it's more like a DTO. I would make a mapper to transform DTO's to  Entity's. Is it because the model in your angular app does not mirroring the entities properties? Also you could use a DataTransformer https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: The objects in the angular app are identical to what the form requires. I tried using data transformers to return idProfessionBranch but end up getting different error messages like this one ```Argument 1 passed to Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\Form\\ChoiceList\\IdReader::getIdValue() must be an object or null, int given"```. I also tried using a datamapper but that didn't work either.

Comment: Did you try to send only the id "professionBranch": ENTITY_ID ?

Comment: You probably need a DataTransformer, can you post the code you wrote for that ?

Comment: @qdequippe yes, as stated in my OP it works when i just provide the professionBranch ID, however i was wondering if there was a way to make the whole JSON object work.

Comment: @zizoujab yes here: 
```public function transform($value)
    {
        return $value->getIdProfessionBranch();
    }

    public function reverseTransform($value)
    {
    }
```